# How can know if bootstrap-validator is running successfully or not?

Tags: validator, cluster, bootstrap

I follows the instructions of Benchmark a Cluster (https://docs.solana.com/cluster/bench-tps), after I executed this line:
NDEBUG=1 ./multinode-demo/bootstrap-validator.sh
according the documentation: Wait a few seconds for the server to initialize. It will print "leader ready..." but my reality is that it’s running unstoppable, the console is full of INFO messages scrolling up rapidly and would not stop after an hour or even longer. Anybody can tell me what's the normal/correct response after running bootstrap-validator.sh?[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngWxP.jpg)[image: screenshot2]

Comment: screenshots of text are never valuable. always prefer code blocks and only of text that you know is relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see lines like this approximately twice per second

```
[2022-08-02T01:20:00.820478731Z INFO  solana_core::replay_stage] new root XXXXXX
```